# Bug report pst-3dplot, where should I submit it?

Tags: pstricks, rotating, auto-pst-pdf, pst-3dplot

I discovered a bug with the `auto-pst-pdf` package, but don't know where to report it.

The bug manifests itself both with `pdflatex` and the `dvi`->`ps`->`pdf` chain. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{$AAA$}
\end{document}
```

The example fails to compile, when it should. The error message is:

```
pdfTeX error (\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format. \end{document}
```

I believe that the bug requires all 3 packages. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with up-to-date `texlive` package installed.

Comment: So what is the bug?

Comment: The file doesn't compile when it should. Edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: I don't believe it requires `rotating`. Just a document with some text seem to replicate the problem. To that end, it may be a bug with the PStricks-side only. Bugs can be reported by sending an email to [the PStricks mailing list](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) (pstricks@tug.org).

Comment: @Werner your comment is the answer to this question. You should post it as an actual answer. I was looking for the mailing list as well

Answer (score 5):

use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
\rotatebox{90}{$AAA$}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

or alternatively:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\else
  \usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\fi
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{$AAA$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{$AAA$}
\end{document}
```

produces no error with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence.